# How can I write a check to test if a variable implements IUnaryNegationOperators if one of the interface's generic paremeters references itself?

Tags: c#, generics, types

Suppose you are given some generic type TOperand. If the operand extends IUnaryNegationOperators the method should return -operand, else throw Error.

Below I've added a example of the Type check I'm trying to preform. I am unable to modify the abstract class Foo and I seem to be unable to preform the type check on line 12.

i

```
using System.Numerics;

public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract TResult test<TOperand, TResult>(TOperand operand);
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override TResult test<TOperand, TResult>(TOperand operand)
    {
        if (operand is IUnaryNegationOperators<TOperand, TResult>)
        {
            // execute some code
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: @gunr2171
For example if you were to try to cast operand to  IUnaryNegationOperators you could do using the following line.
(IUnaryNegationOperators<TOperand, TResult>)  operand;

The problem with this approach is the first type argument of IUnaryNegationOperators must be convertible to IUnaryNegationOperators and TOperand can be any object not just an object that extends IUnaryNegationOperators

Comment: `public override TResult test<TOperand, TResult>(TOperand operand) where TOperand : IUnaryNegationOperators<TOperand>`

Comment: @Dalton - What do you consider a "dynamic type" and why do you want to avoid them?

Comment: Specifically using using the dynamic keyword. Dynamic types would allow me to return -operand but I need more fine control to insure that the operand is extending certain interfaces rather than having one attribute of a interface.

Comment: Are you able to add generic constraints to your method?

Comment: Unfortunately the overwritten method is apart of another library so I am unable to add a generic constraint to it.

Comment: Then use `if (operand is IUnaryNegationOperators<TOperand, TResult> unaryOperand) { // execute some code with unaryOperand }` ie a standard pattern matching check.

Comment: Unfortunately IUnaryNegationOperators constrains its first argument to be ISelf or IUnaryNegationOperators and TOperand could be any type. And I cannot add a generic constraint to TOperand because TOperand is defined in a seperate library(which I don't have control over).

Comment: Could you add all the interfaces and their constraints to the code in question, so we can have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), rather than getting trickles of information in comments?

Comment: In addition please elaborate on why you're "unable to perform the type check on line 12". Is there ary error that hinders you from doing so?

Comment: It throws CS0314, because IUnaryNegationOperators first generic argument has the constraint of implementing IUnaryNegationOperators. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iunarynegationoperators-2?view=net-8.0